# Как с created_at сделать красивую дату. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Как сделать красивую дату в laravel, к примеру с поле в таблицы "created_at"
У меня отображается: `2018-03-02 13:02:20`
А мне нужно, к примеру: `3 февраля, 2018 год. Время: 13:02`
Подскажите может какой-то пакет, где можно красиво настроить. 
И второй вопрос, как настроить точное время (то не  как у меня, записывает на 3 часа позже)
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

в `config/app.php` выставь `'timezone' => 'Europe/Moscow',`
А даты типа `timestamps` возвращаются уже в виде объекта `Carbon`, почитайте - отличная библиотека ([здесь](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/))
Ну... в частности ваш вариант выглядит как то так

```
$model->created_at->format('d F, Y год. Время: H:i');
```

Ну и для локализации нужно доустановить [это](https://github.com/LaravelRUS/localized-carbon)